# How to avoid application start after cancel auto update on startup?

Tags: install4j

Today I need help to deactivate the auto startup of the main application after I abort the update process. The update is triggert automatically during startup so I used the "silent version check" template. But I can't find any option to deactivate the automatic startup.

It is necessary to update the version if there is any newer then the installed one before starting the main application.

I am using version 5.1.5.

Thanks in advance

Hardie

Answer (score 0):

If your requirements are more complex, you cannot use the automatic launcher integration. On the launcher integration tab of the updater, click on "Start integration wizard". The wizard will give you a code snippet that you can invoke in the main method of your application in order to start the updater.

Surround that code snippet with

```
if (UpdateChecker.getUpdateDescriptor(UPDATE_URL,
    ApplicationDisplayMode.GUI).getPossibleUpdateEntry() != null) {
  // code snippet from the integration wizard to launch the updater
```

}

so that the updater is only invoked if an update is available. Then, if you do not receive a call to prepareShutdown, you can display a warning and close the application.